# How do you assign a size limit to a Sequelize array?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize and sequelize migrations to make my postgres models. At the moment, I can't figure out the syntax to assign one of my fields (an array) a size limit. Is it possible to do this?

Right now, the specific field in my migration file shows:

```
industryOfFocus: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)
  }
```

and the specific field in my model.js file shows:

```
industryOfFocus: {
  type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
  allowNull: false,
  validate: { notEmpty: true }
}
```

Is it even possible to assign a size limit with sequelize? I've found no stack overflow questions or sequelize documentation to support the idea that sequelize can set an array's size value. If it's not possible, what would be a work around to assure that my array's size is never over 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a custom validator method. (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#validations)

```
industryOfFocus: {
  type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    isSpecificLength(value) {
      if (value.length !== 3) {
        throw new Error('industryOfFocus must only have three items')
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: this surely does answer my question. Thanks for the help @mcranston18